# Strange autolayout issue since ios 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios11

I have a `UITableViewController` which I present modally (full screen) on iPad.

Since ios11 (and never before) I've got a lots of strange display problem where the `UITableViewController` is apparently, at some point, unable to properly compute its heights, and when I click on a cell actions for another index path is triggered. The controller contains cells which is defined in a xib and the problem disappears if I replace this cell by a vanilla `UITableViewCell`. On the other hand, fixing the height of the cell from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` does not resolve the issue.

Now the strange thing is, if this `TableViewController` is not presented within a new `NavigationController` but is simply pushed from the current view controller, everything works (almost) fine.

I am presenting my controller like that:

`MyTableViewController *tvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Is there anything obviously wrong with the above or that could explain what I am getting ?